Raspberry Pi 5 sometimes has no LAN connection after booting
My raspberry Pi 5 sometimes (about one in seven) boots has no network connection. The Rpi receives an IP address from the DHCP server, but cannot ping any IP address from it. Interestingly, it is possible to ping the Rpi's IP address. The problem will be solved by disconnecting and then connecting the LAN cable or sudo ip link set end0 down and sudo ip link set end0 up. It's totally frustrating. I'm using Raspbian Bookworm with the latest update with Network manager. I know a similar problem was solved with Raspberry Pi 4 by adding genet.force_reneg=n to cmdline.txt. Unfortunately this doesn't work.
Can anyone advise how to resolve this?
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:5a:36:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.180/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute end0
       valid_lft 43095sec preferred_lft 43095sec
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:5a:36:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


dmesg | grep -i end0
[    1.037808] macb 1f00100000.ethernet end0: renamed from eth0
[    4.965317] macb 1f00100000.ethernet end0: PHY [1f00100000.ethernet-ffffffff:01] driver [Broadcom BCM54213PE] (irq=POLL)
[    4.965328] macb 1f00100000.ethernet end0: configuring for phy/rgmii-id link mode
[    9.061093] macb 1f00100000.ethernet end0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control tx



ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev end0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.180 metric 20100 
default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.179 metric 20600 
192.168.100.0/24 dev end0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.180 metric 100 
192.168.100.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.179 metric 600 

If more outputs are needed, I will provide them.
Thanks a lot for any advice!

Just a quick guess before putting in too much more effort. Are you sure there is nothing else on the network with the same IP address? Try disconnecting the Raspberry Pi and pinging it's IP address from another still connected computer just to make sure there is no answer.

The IP address should be fine. I pinged the RPI5 from the router. Router lost ping to RPI IP address while rebooting. After rebooting, ping found the RPI address again.

but cannot ping any IP address from it what output does ping give you?

From 192.168.100.180 icmp_seq=31 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: There is no path to the computer

This sound like the Pi’s network configuration is different at one point from the   One provided by the dhcp server and that there is something changing that is not supposed to change. In other words a configuration problem.  How did you set up this device?

I was able to work around the problem by going into the configuration for eth0, under IPV4. To avoid automatically setting the DHCP server, I chose
METHOD=Automatic(DHCP) Address Only.
After this change, in the same dialog, I modified DNS Server to point to my router 192.168.1.1 -> this of course might be different for you.
I'm guessing that this change modifies the timing for negotiation with the DHCP server and avoids a misconfiguration. Pi has been connecting reliably since I made this change.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

The question was: "Can anyone advise how to resolve this?" So what are u trying to say with this "This does not really answer the question..." flag? It answers it pretty darn well.

You asked a question in Answers (which is not allowed) then possibly answered your own question. See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

I have the exact same problem. You are not alone.  I tried many, many ways to fix it, but nothing works thus far.  I resorted to this script:
!/bin/bash
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
which I invoke by hand upon failure.  It's super annoying.
I have many other devices on my network without such issues, so I know it's not the router.  The issue must be with Pi or its programming.  It's very strange.  Most likely some driver issue or a timing issue with initialization of the IP stack. My problem is just as intermittent as yours. Frequency of the failure varies.  It's only at boot.  Once the connection is solid, it stays that way.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

Hi. I still haven't solved the problem. I tried to resolve it on GitHub with the developers, but to no avail. In my opinion, the problem will not be in Linux, but somewhere in the firmware. I've tried Ubuntu, Raspbian, MxLinux and always the same problem. I even noticed the problem in the Network Installer itself (pressing the SHIFT key while booting), which is before installing Linux. Maybe more support could be pushed at https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1922.
